# Animation with image preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of objects MyObject and that looks like this:

```
var Obj1 = {'ImgTop':'500px','ImgLeft':'200px','ImgSrc':'/image1.jpg'}
var Obj2 = {'ImgTop':'300px','ImgLeft':'100px','ImgSrc':'/image2.jpg'}
```

I load these objects into an array like this:

```
var AnimCycle = new Array(2);

AnimCycle[0] = Obj1;
AnimCycle[1] = Obj2;
```

In my code, there are actually 15 objects loaded in the array. I have function that gets called recursively and inside the function, I have this line:

```
$('#HomeImg').attr('src', AnimCycle[PanelID].ImgSrc);
```

The  problem is that the loading of the image happens when the line is triggered. How can I make the images preload?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: When are you triggering the line? In your document.ready handler?

Comment: `var AnimCycle = [Obj1, Obj2]` is equal to what you have, and is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple script which helps to load images before hand using javascript.

```
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var tempImage = new Image();
        tempImage.src = item.url;
        preloadedImages.push(tempImage);
    }


where data as an array of image data 
data=
{
   name:'NameofImage',
   url:'http://www.website.com/image1.jpg',
}
```

To display the images you can simply add the images to the DOM

```
 $("img").attr({
                src: item.src
            }).appendTo("#target");
```

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/bfJFX/)  which demonstartes the script. It takes data from an ajax request and pre-loads the images. When the user does a mouseover the target it attaches the image to the DOM.

*Below is the screenshot showing the images are being loaded at the time the page gets loaded:*

[image: Net tab of firefox showing the images being preloaded]

this [reference link](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/22/css-throwdown-preload-images-without-javascript/) argues that images loaded in div which are hidden might not be pre-loaded in some of the browsers like Opera. I thought haven't verified it.

*There might be other ways to load images using css if you do not want to use javascript*

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your images in a hidden div in the html:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="/image1.jpg" />
    <img src="/image2.jpg" />
</div>
```

They will be downloaded when the page loads, but they won't be displayed.  Your JavaScript can remain as is.

If you want to do it with script, put this in your ready handler:

```
var imgPreloader = $("<div>").hide().appendTo("body");
$.each(AnimCycle, function() {
    $("<img>").src(this.ImgSrc).appendTo(imgPreloader);
});
```

Comment: OK, that's an interesting idea. I was thinking about storing them in an array; do you think it's better in an array or in a hidden div?